# Adding to JsonArray results with missing elements

Tags: java, arrays, json

I got a missed fields after I am generating (adding to my JsonArray).
I am receiving through ObjectInputStream the below Json String.

```
[{"firstName":"Vasile","lastName":"Petraru","department":"Management","salary":5600},{"firstName":"Ion","lastName":"Andronic","department":"Finante","salary":3222}]

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String a =  new String(inputStream.readObject().toString());
 JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
 JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(a).getAsJsonArray();

 ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
 for(JsonElement obj : jArray){
      Employee b = gson.fromJson(obj,Employee.class);
      employees.add(b);
 }
```

After I'm adding to the JsonArray like this:

```
public String generateJSON() {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    try {
        object.put("Employees", employees);
        array.put(object); // <-- here is the probem...
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array.toString();
}

a = generateJSON();
System.out.println("\nAfter generating: " + a);
// --->

[{"Employees":[{"lastName":"Petraru","salary":5600,"department":"Management"},{"lastName":"Andronic","salary":3222,"department":"Finante"}]}]
```

After generating I'm receiving desired String, but without "firstName" elements... 
Why and how can I solve this? Thanks

Employee class:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String department;
public int salary;

public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String department, int salary){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.department = department;
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Comment: When you put the object in the array are the employee objects populated correctly ?

Comment: sure, i had printed, and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using the employee class you can try something like this :

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("firstName", employee.getFirstName);
jo.put("lastName", employee.getLastName);

JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
ja.put(jo);

JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
mainObj.put("employees", ja);
```

And declare the getters and setters in the Employee class.
Let me know if that works.